# merging multiple partially overlapping dataframes compactly without extra rows and nans

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a bunch of partially overlapping (in rows and columns) pandas DataFrames, exemplified like so:

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame({'a':['1','2','3'], 'b':['a','b','c']})
df2 = pandas.DataFrame({'c':['q','w','e','r','t','y'], 'b':['a','b','c','d','e','f']})
df3 = pandas.DataFrame({'a':['4','5','6'], 'c':['r','t','y']})
...etc.
```

I want to merge them all together with as few NaN holes as possible.

Consecutive blind outer merges invariably give some (unfortunately useless to me) hole-and-duplicate-filled variant of:

> ```
>      a    b  c
> 0    1    a  q
> 1    2    b  w
> 2    3    c  e
> 3  NaN    d  r
> 4  NaN    e  t
> 5  NaN    f  y
> 6    4  NaN  r
> 7    5  NaN  t
> 8    6  NaN  y
> ```

My desired output given a, b, and c above would be this (column order doesn't matter):

> ```
>    a  b  c
> 0  1  a  q
> 1  2  b  w
> 2  3  c  e
> 3  4  d  r
> 4  5  e  t
> 5  6  f  y
> ```

I want the NaNs to be treated as places to insert data from the next dataframe, not obstruct it.

I'm at a loss here. Is there any way to achieve this in a general way?

Answer (score 0):

I can not grantee the speed , But after sort with key , seems work for your sample data.

```
df.apply(lambda x : sorted(x,key=pd.isnull)).dropna(0)
Out[47]: 
     a  b  c
0  1.0  a  q
1  2.0  b  w
2  3.0  c  e
3  4.0  d  r
4  5.0  e  t
5  6.0  f  y
```